# Extending Monitors on Ubuntu 16.04 causes distortion

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

So I've been trying to fix this problem all day. I'm trying to use my TV as an extension of my laptop display through HDMI, but everytime I try to configure the settings to do extended display the resolution goes wacky and it becomes very hard to navigate applications. When display is set to mirrored everything works perfectly fine though. I've only gotten extended display to work once and never agin. Not sure what's wrong. I updated to the latest nvidia drivers. Installed arandr and xrandr. So far nothing has helped.

My laptop is the MSI GS63VR running with a 1060 in it

EDIT:
Not sure if this picture helps, but when I mirror displays this page fits on one screen, when I extend displays it stretches across both

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Qf4.png)

Comment: Please define "wacky" in the sentence *the resolution goes wacky*...

Comment: @CelticWarrior the display gets extended, but everything is zoomed in, and when I try to click icons, i have to click a couple inches to the left of where the actual icon is if I want the click to register.

Comment: Seems to be a resolution issue indeed. After extending have you checked and confirmed that you still have the optimal resolution in the extended one?

Comment: @CelticWarrior once I extend I can't really do much of anything. I tried setting resolution to "auto" before extending, but once the hdmi is plugged in it's almost impossible to get back to the display settings. Is there a way to set this before I plug in the hdmi?

Comment: No, there isn't and before connecting there's no second monitor to extend to either. Now you lost me...

Comment: I mean I can connect it and keep it in mirrored display, and both resolutions are at 1080 and everything is dandy. But when i set one display to extend the resolution messes up and there seems to be no way to fix it.

Comment: Weird indeed. Are you using the Nvidia proprietary driver? If so, which one? If not, why not?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I am. Using 375.